# R programming "Col="red"" error in plot

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to make a plot in R, the part of getting the drawing of the given values works correctly, I'm getting this:
[plot without color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Besm.png)

Using this code:

```
g<- function(x,y)
  + x**2+y**2-3*x+y+2
gb<- function(x) g(x[1],x[2])
x <- seq(-2,2,len=51)
y <- seq(-2,2,len=51)
gz<-outer(x,y,g)
contour(x,y,gz)
polygon(c(0,0,1),c(1,2,1))
```

but when I want to add color to the polygon with this code:

```
 g<- function(x,y)
  + x**2+y**2-3*x+y+2
gb<- function(x) g(x[1],x[2])
x <- seq(-2,2,len=51)
y <- seq(-2,2,len=51)
gz<-outer(x,y,g)
contour(x,y,gz)
polygon(c(0,0,1),c(1,2,1),
        + col="red",
        +density=c(30,40))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"polygon(c(0,0,1),c(1,2,1),
        + col="
```

The only package I am using for my program is: library(mosaicCalc)

Comment: You have a `+` inside your `polygon( c(0,0,1), c(1,2,1), + col="red", + density=c(30,40)`. I think that's causing the error

Comment: @KenS., post as answer? I can imagine OP is mistakenly cutting-and-pasting code that includes continuation characters ... (that or getting confused with ggplot syntax, but the former seems more likely)

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you there is some mistake somewhere in the `polygon()`, so that's the line we'll focus on.

You pasted:

```
polygon(c(0,0,1),c(1,2,1),
    + col="red",
    +density=c(30,40))
```

Which is the same as

```
polygon(c(0,0,1),c(1,2,1), + col="red", +density=c(30,40))
```

The `+` are not supposed to be there and they are causing the error. Use

```
polygon(c(0,0,1),c(1,2,1), col="red", density=c(30,40))
```

and you should be fine.

Sidenote: It seems like you have copy-pasted this code from somewhere and then ran into this error when running it yourself. If someone copies code from their console, it usually includes a `+` if multiple lines of code belong to the same statement. As you've learnt  now, you should remove those before you run the code.